# What's the insight behind A XOR B in bitwise operation?

Tags: bit-manipulation, xor

What I know for `A XOR B` operation is that the output is 1 if `A != B`, and 0 if `A == B`. However, I have no insight about this operation when A and B are not binary.

For example, if `A = 1`, `B = 3`, then `A XOR B = 2`; also, if `A = 2`, `B = 3`, then `A XOR B = 1`. Is there any pattern to the XOR operation for non-binary values?

I have a good understanding of boolean mathematics, so I already understand how XOR works. What I am asking is that how do you, for example, predict the outcome of A XOR B without going through the manual calculation, if A and B are not binaries? Let's pretend that 2 XOR 3 = 1 is not just a mathematical artifact.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to perform the calculation, you can't 'predict' the result.

Comment: `if A and B are not binaries?` What do you mean by that, a machine with a non-binary representation ?

Comment: @wildplasser means A can be 100, B can be 999, not just 1 and 0 (1 digit binary).

Comment: The XOR you imply is the _bitwise_ XOR, which works _in parallel_ on all bits of its operands, assuming a binary representation of the numbers. A _logical_ XOR does exist in theory, but most (all?) C-like languages don't have an operator for it (cause it is seldom needed)

Comment: The XOR you're referring to is a like a boolean operation. The operation is just performed in a bitwise manner (all bits all at once in parallel) on the underlying integer (in its binary representation), each 1 being true, and each 0 being false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at the binary representations of the numbers, and perform the following rules on each bit:

```
0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
```

So, `1 XOR 3` is:

```
1   =  001
3   =  011
XOR =  010  =  2
```

---

To convert a (decimal) number to binary, repeatedly divide by two until you get to 0, and then the remainders in reverse order is the binary number:

[image]

To convert it back, repeatedly subtract it by the largest power of two that's no bigger than it until you get to 0, having each position in the binary number corresponding to the powers you subtracted by set to 1 (the left-most position corresponds to the 0-th power):

[image]

<sup>([Images reference](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary))</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`xor` on integers and other data is simply `xor` of the individual bits:

```
A:    0|0|0|1    = 1
B:    0|0|1|1    = 3
      =======
A^B:  0|0|1|0    = 2

          ^-- Each column is a single bit xor
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use bit operations on numbers that are more than one bit, it simply performs the operation on each corresponding bit in the inputs, and that becomes the corresponding bit in the output. So:

```
A = 1 = 00000001
B = 3 = 00000011
        --------
result= 00000010 = 2

A = 2 = 00000010
B = 3 = 00000011
        --------
result= 00000001 = 1
```

The result has a `0` bit wherever the input bits were the same, a `1` bit wherever they were different.

You use the same method when performing `AND` and `OR` on integers.